# Header is getting merge with first row

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Header position is getting moved along with the Body, when we do the scroll down option, If I used the below code in the css

```
.content-header-row{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
```

The header and first row getting merged. I need to be header position is to be fixed and it need not to be moved while I scroll down the page. Please provide me suggestion on this. Here attached the js fiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/orfgrs23/17/

I can't run through stack overflow snippet, the character count is high. So please see the link and help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want position : fixed, removing that will work

Otherwise, if you want position:fixed, give top:20px(your wish) to the next element(tbody)

Comment: Hi @venkata, When I used the top: 20px on the next Body element, the checkbox only moving down. Not the entire body. Moreover header is still scrolling down. Please provide someother suggestion.

Comment: Have you removed "position:fixed" alone?

Comment: Yes. @venkata. I removed. Please try on jsfiddle of my link too and provide me some suggestion. Thanks for your time

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same in your fiddle and it is working for me !

Comment: header row is still scroll down. It need not to scroll down. It have to stay as sticky type when I scroll down